# Filtering a collection based on another collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I have a `List<businessobject>` object collection and a `List<string>` object collection.  I want filter my `List<businessobject>`so that if a certain property in the business object equals anything the `List<string>` it will be filtered out.  I can think of writing the code this way, but is there any faster or better way?

```
List<businessobject> bo = loadBusinessObjectList();
List<string> stringList = loadStringList();
foreach(businessobject busobj in bo){
   if(stringList.contains(busobj.myProperty))
      bo.remove(busobj)
}
```

Comment: I dont think so, until you are in mood of doing some graph algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler than the rest of the code posted so far...

```
bo.Where(o => !stringList.Contains(o.MyProperty));
```

Answer (score 5):

Your original code will actually not work because you modify the List that you are enumerating.

You can do something like:

```
List<businessobject> bo = loadBusinessObjectList();
List<string> stringList = loadStringList();

var matches = (from b in bo where stringList.Contains(b.SomeProperty) select b);
var bo = bo.Intersect(matches);
```

If you modify

```
List<string> stringList
```

to be

```
HashSet<string> stringList
```

performance would be improved, particularly if the number of strings is large because testing for list membership is O(n), while testing for hashset membership approaches O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Linq is your friend!

```
List<businessobject> boList = loadBusinessObjectList();
List<string> stringList = loadStringList();

var badObjects = from bo in boList
             where stringList.Contains(bo.myProperty)
             select bo;

boList.RemoveRange(badObjects);
```

Comment: Except that returns an `IEnumerable<businessobject>` of things that match.  It does not filter the original list as shown in the OP's code.

Comment: Also, it returns an IEnumerable of things that *do not match* rather than things that do.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<businessobject> bo = loadBusinessObjectList();
List<string> stringList = loadStringList();
List<businesssobject> bo2 = bo.FindAll(obj => !(stringList.contains(obj.myProperty)));
```

Not sure if this is faster. Instead of removing the objects this one creates a new object with only the ones that match.

Comment: This code does not modify the original list as requested by the OP.